# PHP - How to display image source as an img

Tags: php, image, curl, display

I am using Wialon SDK and I am trying to [get a map](http://sdk.wialon.com/wiki/en/pro/remoteapi/apiref/report/get_result_map), everything works fine but it returns a result with image code, and outputs some question marks, (don't know how to explain it, but when you open img file in notepad or something like that) how can I save the output into a png file or display it on web?

here is the function

```
function get_map($sid){
$params = array(
            "width" => 600,
            "height" => 600
         );
$url = "mywebpage.com/ajax.html?svc=report/get_result_map";
$json = json_encode($params);
$ch = curl_init($sid);  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"&params=".$json."&ssid=".$sid);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $server_output;
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
$get_map = $pro->get_map($sid);
var_dump($get_map);
```

Comment: If you don't know how to explain the current output then post it please

Comment: it's something like this but too long:
�PNG  IHDRXX�f�� IDATx���i�Wy>�J�ߨ�

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you need to set the HEADER to tell the browser to display this data as an image.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $get_map; // The PNG data
?>
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Didn't know that... ty!